# react get state value after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

everyone!
I have this code:

```
const [searchOption, setSearchOption] = useState('');

function clearSearchField (){
        setSearchOption("");
        sendQuery();
}

function sendQuery() {
        fetch(`${url}/?search=${searchOption}`,{
            method:'GET'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setIsLoaded(true)
                setError(false)
                setUsersList(result)
            },
            (error) => {
                setIsLoaded(true)
                setError(error)
            }
        )
    }
```

```
<Button variant="outline-secondary" size="lg" className='input-group-text' onClick={sendQuery}>search</Button>
<Button variant="outline-secondary" size="lg" className='input-group-text me-5' onClick={clearSearchField}>X</Button>
```

state searchOption doesn't update when raise sendQuery() function in clearSearchField.
I know that is because of asynchrony.

How to make it work properly? Please help me

I know that in class-component we can use this way:

```
this.setState({
            searchOption: ""
          }, () => ( this.sendQuery() ));
```

In function-component we can use useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
        sendQuery();
    }, [searchOption])
```

but it will send query every time when searchOption changes. But I need it clears searchOption and sends query only when user clicks on X-button

Comment: you want setSearchOption to trigger after you click the button that contains sendQuery?

Comment: when user clocks on X-button, I want set searchOption as ""(empty str), after that I want raise sendQuery function (which use searchOption state)

Comment: `sendQuery` _doesn't_ seem to use `searchOption`.

Comment: i mean there is a hacky way of doing it using a useState with a boolean that is there just to change from true to false and the use effects will use that boolean to trigger instead of the searchOption but im sure there is a cleaner and better way of doing this

Comment: I fixed, searchOption is needed for query

Comment: you could prob also use useRef instead of useState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should accept searchOption as an argument for the sendQuery method, like this

```
function sendQuery(searchOption) {
    fetch(`${url}/?search=${searchOption}`,{
        method:'GET'})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            setIsLoaded(true)
            setError(false)
            setUsersList(result)
        },
        (error) => {
            setIsLoaded(true)
            setError(error)
        }
    )
}
```

Also if you don't want the sendQuery function to be called again and again whenever the searchOption changes I'd suggest that you don't pass the searchOption in useEffect's parameter. In that way the sendQuery function  will only trigger once when the component is mounted and then you can normally run sendQuery only on click of X button or search button.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code will fix your problem but I don't know if it is the most optimal way to solve this problem. Also, I haven't tested it but I think this should work.

```
function Component() {
const [searchOption, setSearchOption] = useState('');

function clearSearchField (){
        const newSearchOption = "";
        setSearchOption(newSearchOption);
        sendQuery(newSearchOption); 
}

// send query takes a string parameter now
function sendQuery(searchOptionString) {
    fetch(`${url}/?search=${searchOptionString}`,{
        method:'GET'})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            setIsLoaded(true)
            setError(false)
            setUsersList(result)
        },
        (error) => {
            setIsLoaded(true)
            setError(error)
        }
    )
}

return (
    <>
        <Button 
            variant="outline-secondary" 
            size="lg" 
            className='input-group-text' 
            onClick={() => sendQuery(searchOption)}
        >
            search
        </Button>
        <Button 
            variant="outline-secondary" 
            size="lg" 
            className='input-group-text me-5' 
            onClick={clearSearchField}
        >
            X
        </Button>
    </>
);
```

}

Comment: Once the function is called, onClick of the first button: () => sendQuery(searchOption) is set to an updated value of searchOption. When you call clearSearchField, sendQuery will get the correct value and won't depend on the updated value of searchOption.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put some logic inside useEffect that determines the execution based on the state value of searchOption?

like

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if(searchOption.length > 0) sendQuery();
    }, [searchOption])
```

Comment: because it will send search query every time when serachOption became "". Emen when user delete all symbols from input. But I need sendQuery() to be rased olny when user click on the button

Comment: I see, maybe as a way to solve it without increasing the complexity of the code
I think there might be a way to manage the state of searchOption as an object.

`searchOption = {
value: string;
clear: boolean
}`
So in useEffect, check the clear value of searchOption.